# What is the use of map method in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have been googling and not getting the real usage of the `map` method. Here is what i tried in my console.

```
a = ["kevin","john","ryan"]
a.each {|i| puts i.upcase}
```

The above would print the values in **caps**.

```
a = ["kevin","john","ryan"]
a.map {|i| puts i.upcase}
```

This would also print the values in **caps**. So what's so special in map method? and also can anyone lead me to a good source for this topic for better understanding.

Comment: Have you tried reading the documentation on those methods? For example: [Enumerable#map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map).

Comment: That's a `ruby` question, so i changed the tag and the title.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: Apologize,  I am pretty new to ruby and rails, the docs are not clear to me....

Comment: Just curious - which docs are you reading that are not clear?

Comment: In the case of `map`, it will execute what's in the block and do the `puts` just like `each` does, but it is also collecting the return values of your `puts` statements into an array and returning that as a result. That result is useless to you, so there's no point in using `map` in that case. You'll get an array of `nil`s. `each` executes what's inside the block without collecting any results.

Comment: @mbratch : does it create a new array with the results, if so how can i access it.

Comment: @Kevin Save it to a variable.

Comment: @Kevin, yes, just assign it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, when you want to print each value individually right away, [`each`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-each) is better. [`map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) is useful when you want to save the new versions your elements back into an array, and use that data later in your program.

For instance, say you wanted to forget whether the names had ever been lower or uppercase. Everywhere in your program, the names will be uppercase, so you just want to convert them to uppercase now and be done with that.

```
a = ["kevin","john","ryan"]
a = a.map{ |n| n.upcase }
```

Compare that to using `each` – you would have to use `each_with_index`, actually, since you need a way to assign the new values back:

```
a = ["kevin","john","ryan"]
a.each_with_index do |n, i|
  a[i] = n.upcase
end
```

This is the kind of situation `map` is for. Getting a new `Enumerable` with changed values, so that you can use the new values later.

By the way, as a shortcut, if you’re assigning a `map`ped variable back to itself, instead of `a = a.map{}`, you can use `a.map!{}`.

Another situation is if you wanted to print all names with an even number of letters. If you used `each`, here’s how it would look:

```
a = ["kevin","john","ryan"]
a.each do |n|
  if n.size.even?
    puts n.upcase
  end
end
```

If you used `map`, that would give you an array back. Then you could pass that array to [`select`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-select), and finally use `each` to print the values. This separates the steps more clearly for anyone reading the code, and makes your code more modular if you want to extend it later.

```
a = ["kevin","john","ryan"]
a.map(&:upcase) \
 .select{ |n| n.size.even? } \
 .each{ |n| puts n }
```

The last line could also be this:

```
 .each(&Kernel.method(:puts))
```

but that is probably unnecessarily confusing for such a small bit of code. What that does is convert the global `puts` method into a block using the `&` operator. `Kernel` holds all global methods, and `.method` is the way you get a variable with a method from a class. So `.each(&Kernel.method(:puts))` says “get the global `puts` method, and turn it into a block so that `puts` is called with the block arguments as parameters”. But in this case, it’s clearer and simpler to write `.each{ |n| puts n }`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, just at the last line a.map(&:upcase) instead of a.map(:upcase)... and also final question... each returns comma separated values and map and collect returns an array.

Comment: I think you might mean something like this: `a.map(&:upcase).select { |n| n.size.even? } .each(&Kernel.method(:puts))` for that last example.

Comment: @NickVeys You’re right, I had messed up `select` and `puts`. As for the `&:upcase` vs. `:upcase`, I thought that `map` also worked when given a symbol in later versions of Ruby, but it seems not. Maybe that’s just a Rails ActiveSupport extension. I fixed that too.

Comment: @Kevin As for your final question, when you call the methods on an `Array`, both [`map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) and [`collect`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-collect) (they are different names for the same method) return the new, changed `Array`. However, [`each`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-each) doesn’t return “comma separated values” – it just returns the original, unchanged `Array` (which *is* usually displayed with commas between the values). So all three methods return `Array`s – some new, some old.

Comment: If i am not troubling you too much, can you edit your answer and update this part on what .each(&Kernel.method(:puts)) Kernal.method does here. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 1):

`map` (or `collect`) collects the output of the block in an array.

Your example is not that useful; the block is used only for its side-effects.

Compare with `a.map { |i| i.upcase }` or, more Ruby-y, `a.collect(&:upcase)`:

```
 > a2 = a.collect(&:upcase)
=> ['KEVIN', 'JOHN', 'RYAN']
```

`each` simply returns the value that it was called on, in this case, the original array.

Without the output of `puts` shown:

```
 > a2 = a.each(&:upcase)
=> ['kevin', 'john', 'ryan']
```

If you collect the output of `puts` you'll get an array of nils:

```
 > a2 = a.collect { |i| puts i.upcase }
=> [nil, nil, nil]
```

Comment: You should compare that with `each` to show differences. OP seems to confuse the two.

Answer (score 1):

- Whatever is printed by `puts` is the *side effect* of evaluating the block. Regarding the side effect of evaluating the block, `each` and `map` are the same.
- Besides side effect (which some methods do not have), all Ruby methods have a *return value*. It is the return value that differs between `each` and `map`. The former returns the receiver, the latter returns the result of the evaluation of the block.

  ```
  b = a.each{|i| puts i.upcase}
  b # => ["kevin","john","ryan"]

  b = a.map{|i| puts i.upcase}
  b # => ["KEVIN","JOHN","RYAN"]
  ```

Answer (score 1):

In the case of `map`, it will execute what's in the block and do the `puts` just like `each` does, but it is also collecting the return values of your puts statements into an array and returning that as a result. That result is useless to you, so there's no point in using map in that case. You'll get an array of `nil`s. each executes what's inside the block without collecting any results.

`each` executes the block and just returns the original array:

```
> a = ["kevin","john","ryan"]
=> ["kevin", "john", "ryan"]
> a.each {|i| puts i.upcase}
KEVIN
JOHN
RYAN
=> ["kevin", "john", "ryan"]
>
```

`map` executes the block and returns the values of what's in the block in an array:

```
> a = ["kevin","john","ryan"]
=> ["kevin", "john", "ryan"]
> a.map {|i| puts i.upcase}
KEVIN
JOHN
RYAN
 => [nil, nil, nil]
>
```

Note the returned array of `nil`, since each `puts` returned a `nil` and `map` collected those. If you want to collect the upper case strings in an array, you'd use `map` properly like this:

```
> a.map  {|i| i.upcase}
=> ['KEVIN', 'JOHN', 'RYAN']
```

Or, equivalently, `a.map(&:upcase)`. You can also assign it to a variable:

```
> foo = a.map  {|i| i.upcase}
=> ['KEVIN', 'JOHN', 'RYAN']
> foo
=> ['KEVIN', 'JOHN', 'RYAN']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer to mbratch... thanks